# Obtener valor de variable de funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Deseo obtener el valor de un resultado de una funcion para despues mostrarla en consola, pero lo unico que me devuelve es el valor con el que se inicializa.
Esta es mi función:

```
function calculos(elemento) {
    var tr = $(elemento).parent().parent().parent();
    var cantidad = $(tr).find('td div input.cantidad').val();
    var tarifa = $(tr).find('td div input.precio').val();
    var tipo_tarifa = $(tr).find('td div select.tipo_tarifa').val();
    var total = 0;
    var tipoCompra = $(tr).find('th div select.tipo_compra').val();
    var ponerTotal = $(tr).find('td div input.total');
    var meses = $(tr).find('td div input.meses').val();
    var dias = $(tr).find('td div select.dias').val();
    var horas = $(tr).find('td div select.horas').val();
    switch (tipoCompra) {
        case 'Unica':
            total += cantidad * tarifa;
            $(ponerTotal).val(total);
            break;
        case 'Recurrente':
            switch (tipo_tarifa) {
                case 'anual':
                    total += ((cantidad * tarifa))
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total + ' Anuales');
                    break;
                case 'mensual':
                    total += ((cantidad * tarifa))
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total + ' Mensuales');
                    break;
                case 'dia':
                    total += ((cantidad * tarifa))
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total + ' Al día');
                    break;
                case 'hora':
                    total += ((cantidad * tarifa))
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total + ' Por hora');
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'Temporal':
            switch (tipo_tarifa) {
                case 'anual':
                    total += ((tarifa * cantidad) / 12 * meses) + ((tarifa * cantidad) / 12 / 30 * dias) + ((tarifa * cantidad) / 12 / 30 / 24 * horas);
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total);
                    break;
                case 'mensual':
                    total += ((tarifa * cantidad) * meses) + ((tarifa * cantidad) * dias / 30) + ((tarifa * cantidad) / 30 / 24 * horas);
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total)
                    break;
                case 'dia':
                    total += ((tarifa * cantidad) * dias) + ((tarifa * cantidad) / 24 * horas) + ((tarifa * cantidad) * 30 * meses);
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total)
                    break;
                case 'hora':
                    total += ((tarifa * cantidad) * horas) + ((tarifa * cantidad) * 24 * dias) + ((tarifa * cantidad) * 24 * 30 * meses);
                    $(ponerTotal).val(total);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Al finalizar esa función necesito mostrar el valor al darle click a un botón. La funcion de mi codigo es la siguiente:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addhardware', function () {
var total = calculos(this);
console.log(total)
if (error.length == 0 && tipo_compra != 0 && proveedor != 0 && categoria != 0 && precio != '' && fechaCompra != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/portafolio/AgregarProyecto/inserthardware",
            data: {
                total: total
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //$("#tbodyhardware").append(response);
                var id = response
                var oculto = $(tr).find('th div input.ocultohardware').val(id);
                var update = $(tr).find('td button.addhardware').removeClass('addhardware').addClass('updateHardware');
                Swal.fire('¡Guardado!', '¡Los datos han sido guardados exitosamente!', 'success');
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (error, status, xhr) {
                console.log(error)
                console.log(status)
                console.log(xhr)
            }
        });
    } else {
        Swal.fire('¡Datos incompletos!', '¡Por favor llena los campos que son requeridos!', 'error')
    }
}
```

Los calculos los realiza correctamente, no hay ningún problema por esa parte, pero requiero obtener el valor de total para posteriormente mandar ese valor a una base de datos. Espero que me puedan ayudar

Esta es la interfaz de mi aplicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo HTML seria el siguiente:

```
<tr id="contenidohardware" style="display:none" class="hardware">
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <input type="hidden" name="" class="ocultohardware">
                                <?php if (isset($grals)): ?>
                                <?php if ($grals->num_rows() > 0): ?>
                                <?php foreach ($grals->result() as $q): ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="" class="idprohard" value="<?php echo $q->id_datos_grals ?>">
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                                <?php endif;?>

                                <?php
if (isset($datos)) {
    if ($datos->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($datos->result() as $row) {
            $status = $row->status;
            $project_m = $row->id;
            $idMa = $row->project_m;
            $ho = $this->Administracion->idProjectM($idMa);
            if ($ho->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($ho->result() as $row) {
                    $idUser = $row->id_usuarios;
                    ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="" class="idmahard" value="<?php echo $idUser ?>">
                                <?php }}}}}?>
                                <?php if (isset($_POST['id'])) {$id = $_POST['id'];?>
                                <input type="hidden" class="i" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id">
                                <?php }?>
                                <select required name="" id="" class="form-control tipo_compra">
                                    <option class="tc" value="0">Seleccionar</option>
                                    <option class="tic" value="Unica">Unica</option>
                                    <option class="tic" value="Recurrente">Recurrente</option>
                                    <option class="tic" value="Temporal">Temporal</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <!-- Proveedor -->
                                <select class="form-control proveedor" name="" id="proveedor">
                                    <option class="prov" value="0">Seleccionar Proveedor</option>
                                    <?php
if (isset($prov)) {
    if ($prov->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($prov->result() as $fila) {
            if ($fila->nombreTipo == 'hardware' && $fila->aprobado == 1) {
                // echo $fila->nombreProveedor;
                ?>
                                    <option class="<?php echo $fila->id_proveedor ?>"
                                        value="<?php echo $fila->nombreProveedor ?>">
                                        <?php echo $fila->nombreProveedor ?></option>
                                    <?php
}
        }
    }
}
?>
                                    <!-- <?php if (isset($proveedor)): ?>
                                    <?php if ($proveedor->num_rows() > 0): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($proveedor->result() as $r): ?>
                                    <option class="<?php echo $r->id_proveedor ?>"
                                        value="<?php echo $r->nombreProveedor ?>">
                                        <?php echo trim($r->nombreProveedor); ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <?php endif;?> -->
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <!-- Categoria -->
                                <select class="form-control categoria" name="" id="categoria">
                                    <option id="cat2" class="cat2" value="0">Seleccionar Categoría
                                    </option>
                                    <?php if (isset($categoria)): ?>
                                    <?php if ($categoria->num_rows() > 0): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($categoria->result() as $row): ?>
                                    <?php if ($row->nombre == 'otro'): ?>
                                    <option class="<?php echo $row->id_proveedor ?>" id="<?php echo $row->id ?>"
                                        value="<?php echo $row->otraCategoria ?>">
                                        <?php echo $row->otraCategoria; ?></option>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                    <option class="<?php echo $row->id_proveedor ?>" id="<?php echo $row->id ?>"
                                        value="<?php echo $row->nombre ?>">
                                        <?php echo $row->nombre; ?></option>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <option id="otro" class="otro" value="otro">Otro
                                    </option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <!-- Producto/servicio -->
                                <select class="form-control producto" name="" id="producto">
                                    <option class="pro" value="0">Seleccionar Producto o Servicio
                                    </option>
                                    <?php if (isset($producto)): ?>
                                    <?php if ($producto->num_rows() > 0): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($producto->result() as $row): ?>
                                    <option class="<?php echo $row->id_categoria; ?>"
                                        value="<?php echo $row->nombreProducto; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $row->nombreProducto; ?></option>
                                    <?php echo $row->nombreProducto ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                    <option class="otroProducto" value="otro">Otro
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                                <input style="display: none" type="text" class="form-control inputOtro">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <textarea class="form-control descripcion" name="des" id="" cols="30"
                                    rows="1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control precio" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <select name="" id="tipo_tarifa" class="form-control form-inline tipo_tarifa">
                                    <option class="tTarifa" value="0">Seleccionar</option>
                                    <option value="anual">Anual</option>
                                    <option value="mensual" selected="true">Mensual</option>
                                    <option value="dia">Día</option>
                                    <option value="hora">Hora</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <input class="form-control url" type="url" name="url" id="url" size="30">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control cantidad" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control meses" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <select name="" id="" class="form-control dias">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</3option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                    <option value="24">24</option>
                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                    <option value="26">26</option>
                                    <option value="27">27</option>
                                    <option value="28">28</option>
                                    <option value="29">29</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                                <select name="" id="" class="form-control horas">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                </select>
                        </td>
            </div>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <input disabled type="text" class="form-control form-inline total" value="">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" class="form-control fechaCompraHard" required min=<?php $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
echo $hoy;?> />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-warning addhardware"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class=" btn btn-danger deletehardware"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: ¿Y donde quieres mostrar el valor?  No veo ningun elemento HTML donde ponerlo, aunque imagino que sera un `input` para luego ejecutar el `submit` que captarás desde javascript usando ajax y asi poder mandarlo a la base de datos, ¿no? ¿es eso lo que quieres?  Pues ponnos el HTML y el javascript con ajax que falta (a menos que quieras hacerlo de forma tradicional con un action apuntando al php y mostrar una nueva pagina con el resultado)

Comment: Ya agregué el HTML correspondiente y tambien capturas de pantalla de la aplicación

Comment: Ahora te falta el código PHP de `/portafolio/AgregarProyecto/inserthardware` para que veamos que haces alli, pues es alli donde debes lanzar tu consulta SQL que estas pidiendo seguramente.